# lim$_{n→∞}d(x_n, a) \neq d($lim$_{n→∞}x_n, a)$ in Metric Space - Implications

Tags: limits, metric-spaces, compactness, function-and-relation-composition, complete-spaces

A Metric Space $<M,d>$ is given by the Metric $M$ and distance function $d$

If there exists a Cauchy Sequence $x_n$ such that:

lim$_{n→∞}d(x_n, a) \neq d($lim$_{n→∞}x_n, a)$, for some $a \in M$ what can we imply about the Metric Space?

In particular, I'm curious if this affects the compactness/completeness of the metric space.

Comment: $d(x)$ alone is not defined, do you mean $d(x,a)$ or something?

Comment: Of course, edited! Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a misconception here that it would be good to clear up. Let's talk about something more concrete for a second. The limit of $\sin(x)$ as $x$ tends to infinity does not exist. So it is wrong to say $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)=0.$$ *But* it is *also* wrong to say $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)\ne0.$$There simply is no such thing as $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)$; if you say $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)\ne0$ that implies that there is such a thing as that limit, it just doesn't equal $0$.

So now for your question. Let's give that inequation a name. You ask what happens if $$\lim_{n\to\infty}d(x_n,a)\ne d(\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n,a).\quad(*)$$The answer is that (*) simply never happens. It's like asking what happens when $0=1$.

Because if $\lim x_n$ *exists* then we can prove that $(*)$ is false. But if $\lim x_n$ does not exist that does not mean $(*)$ is true. If $\lim x_n$ does not exist then $(*)$ is neither true nor false - it's meaingless, since it says something about non-existent things.

**Why it matters:** One might say this is not all that important; if someone cluefull says $\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin(x)\ne0$ that may not be quite correct, but a cluefull reader knows what he meant, so what's the harm?

The harm is when newbies talk about limits that don't exist. This all started with a certain exercise the OP had to do. He's said he had a solution. I've suspected his solution was wrong, and he just confirmed that what he did is indeed the wrong thing I suspected. And the wrong solution comes about precisely from talking about nonexistent limits as though they existed. Here it is:

**Exercise** Say $M=\{x\in\Bbb R^2:||x||<1\}$. Define a metric on  $M$ by saying $d(x,y)=2-||x||-||y||$ for $x\ne y$, $d(x,x)=0$. Show that $M$ is not  complete.

**Wrong Solution** Let $x_n=(1-1/n,0)$. Then $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $M$. (Fine so far.) Now $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=(1,0)\notin M$. So $M$ is not complete. QED.

That solution really is wrong, not just poorly expressed or lacking details. *If* one somehow has the idea that we can always write $\lim x_n$ then it's easy to see where the wrong solution comes from; after all, what else could the limit be?

For anyone who thinks that "totally wrong" is putting it too strongly: if there *is* a sort of sensible version of the proof it would involve something like saying $S=\{x:||x||\le1\}$, and using the same formula to define a metric on $S$. But that same formula does *not* define a metric on $S$.

Or to put it another way: For that sequence $x_n$, any moderately plausible (but of course wrong) argument showing that $\lim x_n=(1,0)$ will *also* show that $\lim x_n=(0,1)$. (Because if we ignore the fact that the following $d$'s are undefined and just blindly appply the formula we get $d((1,0),x_n)=d((0,1),x_n)$.)

Comment: A uniformly convergent function preserves the Cauchy property.

Comment: A uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences, yes. I don't see how that contradicts anything I wrote. The fact that a uniformly continuous function preserves Cauchy sequences doesn't show that it makes sense to talk about things that simply don't exist.

Comment: Can we assume the limit exists. Then show that lim$_{n→∞}d(x_n, a) \neq d($lim$_{n→∞}x_n, a)$. Get a contradiction. This implies the limit does not exist. Hence, the space is incomplete?

Comment: @GregoryPeck If it's possible to do what you say then yes that would  be a valid proof of incompleteness. I suspect this all has to do with that other problem with the $2-||x||-||y||$ thing. In that problem (i) I don't believe you're going to be able to do this, and (ii) showing the incompleteness is very simple _without_ this argument! Simply assume that $x\in M$ and show that $d(x,x_n)$ does not tend to zero.

Comment: I managed to prove it as you said in (ii), after a more rigorous re-examination of yesterday's comments. I was a bit tired. This question is just me wondering about using this approach if I was very stuck. Also, how did you come to that conclusion in (i)? And if lim$_{n→∞}d(x_n, a) = d($lim$_{n→∞}x_n, a)$, we can't imply from this that the limit exists, can we?

Comment: @GregoryPeck You might want to show us the proof before handing it in. (If you want me to see it look up how "notifications" work - note the notification has to be the _start_ of the comment.) There is no conclusion in (i), just an opinion. I can't imagine how such a proof would go.

Comment: @GregoryPeck "And if $\lim d(x_n,a)=d(\lim x_n,a)$ we can't imply from this that the limit exists, can we? " Sigh. Sigh squared. The question makes no sense! You can't _write_ $d(\lim x_n,a)$ in the first place _unless_ you know the limit exists. The notion of deducing the existence of the limit from that equation is simply incoherent - you can't _possibly_ show that equation holds if you don't already know the limit exists.

Comment: Of course, makes sense. *Facepalm*. If I get a chance before my exam tomorrow, I'll show you how we used these limits to prove incompleteness, and you can determine its correctness.

Comment: @GregoryPeck If you have time... the right argument is very very short. Let $x_n=(1-1/n,0)$. Assume that $x\in M$. Then $d(x,x_n)=\dots\ge\dots>0$, so $x_n$ does not converge to $x$. Took me about a minute to type that - _if_ you've found the right argument it takes about two minutes - type what I just typed except fill in the blanks.

Comment: If I can recall correctly I showed that sequence converged to $(1,0)$ which of course was not in the set $M$. So $d((1,0),x_n) = 0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$

Comment: @GregoryPeck Aha! That's how I _thought_ your proof was going to go. Thinking that that's what your proof was like is exactly why I posted my answer in this thread. What you're saying here is one hundred percent totally and completely wrong. Not close, not just sloppy or badly put, it's totally wrong. Why? Because it is not true that the sequence converges to $(1,0)$. There _is no such thing_ as $d((1,0),x_n)$, because $d(x,y)$ is only defined for $x,y\in M$.

Comment: @GregoryPeck To be fair, it's easy to see how you got the idea that that's how the proof is supposed to work - like you see a proof that the rationals are incomplete based on a Cauchy sequence of rationals that converges to $\sqrt 2$. But that proof works _because_ $\Bbb Q$ is a subset of the larger metric space $\Bbb R$. In this problem there _is_ no such larger metric space! If you say $S=\{x:||x||\le 1\}$ the formula for $d$ that defines the metric on $M$ does _not_ define a metric on $S$. (For example, that formula would imply that $d((1,0),(0,1))=0$.)

Comment: @GregoryPeck Which is why it's an excellent exercise - ir forces you to get a few things straight. Like, the definition of "M is not complete" is _not_ "there is a Cauchy sequence in $M$ with limit not in $M$". (What is the definition? I've said many times. How _do_ you prove $M$ is not complete? I've said many times, including a few comments ago in this thread,) The exercise forces you to get a few things straight, but you continue to repeat the same errors over and over and over, no matter how  many times I explain that they're wrong.

Comment: That seems to make total sense to me now. Yes, the confusion was to do with an example I saw in $\mathbb{Q}$ which converged to an irrational where the metric was the same on both spaces. I became narrow-minded. Cauchy = does not converge in $M$. In your comment you have $d(x,x_n) = ... \geq ... > 0$. So we have $d(x,x_n) = 2 - ||x|| - ||x_n||.$ Since $||x||<1, ||x_n|| < 1$ we have that $d(x,x_n)>0$. I'm guessing this is incorrect. Since using the sequence $\frac{1}{n} $ in $ \mathbb{R}$ would give the same result. i.e - always greater than $0$. Yet it converges to $0$.

Comment: @GregoryPeck We're getting closer. But no, just showing that $d(x,x_n)>0$ is not enough. We need to show that there is _one_ number $c>0$ such that $d(x,x_n)>c$ for all $n$. (Well, we're required to get $d(x,x_n)>c$ only for infinitely many $n$, but here it happens to be true for all $n$.) I gave you that template and asked you to fill in the blanks. You filled in the first blank but _skipped_ the second. Think about it. For _every_ $n$ we have $2-||x||-||x_n||\ge\dots>0$. (Where the thing you put in the blank is not allowed to depend on $n$.)

Comment: @GregoryPeck Hint: You used two inequalities, $||x||<1$ and $||x_n||<1$. Forget one of them and just use the other one...

Comment: Blank = $2-2||x||$ > 0?

Comment: @GregoryPeck No, there's no reason $2-||x||-||x_n||>2-2||x||$. Look: The fact that $||x_n||<1$ implies that $2-||x||-||x_n||$ is greater than _what_? $2-a-b=(1-a)+(1-b)$.

Comment: @GregoryPeck Hallalujah! For every $n$ we have $d(x,x_n)>1-||x||>0$, so $d(x,x_n)$ does not tend to zero, so $x_n$ does not tend to $x$. (That's 99 percent right; actually the inequality holds only when $x\ne   x_n$. But if it happens that $x=x_N$ then the inequality holds for all $n>N$, good enough.)

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot for all the help!

Comment: @GregoryPeck No problem. Wait til you get my bill...

Comment: If you're billing me, one more question won't make a huge difference. In relation to the original question here, we used 2 sequences. $a_n = (\frac{1}{n+1},0)$ and $b_n = (\frac{-1}{n+1},0)$. I'm pretty sure both these sequences are defined in $M$, unless I'm missing something (which is not unlikely). We have lim$_{n→∞}d(a_n, b_n) =2$ and $ d($lim$_{n→∞}a_n, $lim$_{n→∞}b_n) = 0$. Since they're not equal we can go through the right process and show the limit doesn't exist?

Comment: @GregoryPeck Sigh cubed. I'm not sure what you're asking, but it is not true that $d(\lim a_n,b_n)=0$. Makes no sense, because there is no such thing as $\lim a_n$.

Comment: I just edited, I always make a mistake with this Math Latex. Too much copying and pasting

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying now, let me think. Oops.

Comment: @GregoryPeck You just edited. Now the same error appears twice! IF A LIMIT DOES NOT EXIST YOU CANNOT WRITE EQUATIONS THAT INCLUDE THAT LIMIT.

Comment: @GregoryPeck Once and for all, to answer every question you will ever have about limits in that metric space: If $x\ne y$ then $d(x,y)\ge 1-||x||$. It follows that there are _no_ convergent sequences in $M$ (except for the trivial ones, where $x_n=x$ for all $n>N$).

Comment: Of course, I'm trying to propose an alternate proof: We assume the limits to $a_n$ and $b_n$ both exist. We then show a contradiction, that is $0 = 2$. Hence, one of those limits doesn't exist. And since both are Cauchy we have that a Cauchy sequence exists without a limit in $M$. Hence, the space is incomplete. (This is all assuming both sequences do exist in $M$ which I think is the case).

Comment: @GregoryPeck I actually have things to do... Why are you doing this? And more important, _assuming_ that both limits exist, _how_ do you deduce that $d(\lim a_n,\lim b_n)=0$? I don't see how that follows. (Unless you're also assuming that $\lim a_n=\lim b_n$, in which case this is _not_ a proof that $M$ is not complete).

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Sorry for wasting your time.

Answer (score 3):

In this case,the Cauchy sequence is not converging. The map $x\mapsto d(x,a)$ is uniformly continous, so $n\mapsto d(x_n, a)$ must converge.  The space cannot be complete and therefore it is not compact.

Comment: This makes no sense. The question was what can we say if $\lim d(x_n,a)\ne d(\lim x_n,a)$. It _cannot happen_ that $\lim d(x_n,a)\ne d(\lim x_n,a)$! As you point out, if $\lim x_n$ exists then $\lim d(x_n,a)= d(\lim x_n,a)$ . But that doesn't mean $\lim d(x_n,a)\ne d(\lim x_n,a)$ if $\lim x_n$ does not exist. If $\lim x_n$ does not exist then there's no such thing as d(\lim x_n,a)$ either. Something cannot be unequal to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: It makes complete sense, since uniformly continuous functions preserve the Cauchy property of sequences.  There is no "cauchyness" as $x\to\infty$.

Comment: When I said this made no sense probably that wasn't exactly what I meant. Everything you say in your post is of course correct. What makes no sense to me is this as an answer to the OP - he asked what would happen if ($*$) (where that's as in my answer below). What you write is not what happens if ($*$). Because ($*$) simply never happens.